# Disable custom Tkinter Slider

Tags: tkinter, customtkinter

Does anybody know a way to disable a custom Tkinter slider?

Most tkinter widgets have a configure option to set state='DISABLED'.
The custom tkinter Slider does not have this attribute though.

Can anybody propose a way to achieve it?
Many thanks

Comment: I'm not super familiar with customtkinter's implementations, but you *might* be able to bind mouse events like `'<Button>'` and `'<Motion>'` to `'break'` so the user can't interact with the widget - you'd probably also want to set the colors to grays as well. E.g.: `my_slider.bind('<Button-Motion>', 'break')` will dispose of all "moving the mouse while holding it down" events

Comment: According to https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkSlider there is a `state` attribute that can be set to `disabled`, is that not what you need?

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions. The state attribute is missing from the configure() method. So slider.conifgure(state ='normal) just raises an error

Comment: I have not been able to achieve anything using: slider.bind("<Enter>", 'break') ,slider.bind("<Button-1>", 'break'), slider.bind("<B1-Motion>", 'break') and variations on that theme...

Comment: Maybe it is a version issue? I just installed `customtkinter` version 5.1.2 and then `slider = customtkinter.CTkSlider(master=app, from_=0, to=100, command=slider_event)
slider.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
slider.configure(state="disabled")` works fine, i.e., no errors and the slider gets disabled.